# android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView does not account for current theme

Tags: android, android-theme

I made a custom keyboard for my app using the tutorial [here](http://www.fampennings.nl/maarten/android/09keyboard/index.htm). It uses the android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView object (for which I find very few examples).

However, this makes a keyboard that resembles older android versions, and does not adapt to the phone's default theme.

Is there an easy way to make the keyboard appear by default according to the current user's keyboard?